# EF7 Beta 4 : AddEntityFramework dont accept argument (Configuration)

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am going through this example:
http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/01/17/asp-net-5-and-angularjs-part-4-using-entity-framework-7

and i am struggling with this code part:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using creaservo.com.Models;
using Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;

namespace creaservo.com
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            // Setup configuration sources.
            Configuration = new Configuration()
                .AddJsonFile("config.json")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }


        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            // Register Entity Framework
            services.AddEntityFramework(Configuration)
                .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<MoviesAppContext>();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

The Problem is with

```
        // Register Entity Framework
        services.AddEntityFramework(Configuration)
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<MoviesAppContext>();
```

where i get a build error:

```
Error   CS1501  No overload for method 'AddEntityFramework' takes 1 arguments
```

I saw in a lot of other examples the same use of a argument for Configuration.

No idea, what's wrong....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the tutorial you're following is using an older version of the EF7 framework. EntityFramework 7 beta 4 no longer accepts any parameters to `AddEntityFramework`. It looks like beta 5 is still on this same track, too.

I believe what you're looking for is this:

```
// Register Entity Framework
services.AddEntityFramework()
    .AddSqlServer()
    .AddDbContext<MoviesAppContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.Get("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"));
    });
```

This simplifies the structure that you need in the configuration file, because the `MoviesAppContext` only needs the connection string, not the `EntityFramework` and `Data` elements.

Comment: I'm not saying it simplifies the code; it reduces the dependencies on the structure of your config files. Of course, it could be simplified to `options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString)` if you have it in a variable already - you're no longer dependent on a Configuration object at all.

Comment: I agree and was being a bit of a smart alec. I'm a little frustrated as this EF7 code seems to be in flux without much documentation. How do you create an in-memory dbcontext that sits next to the SQL one. Should be something like Options.UseInMemoryStore() ?

Comment: Well, it is "beta" for a reason. For me, it's been both frustrating and entertaining to dig through Microsoft's code instead of documentation. I'm really not sure - I haven't used EF7's memory store. Open a question and perhaps someone will have an answer for you!

Comment: Thanks. Will do. Seems like a moving target as this seems to be changing between beta 4 and 5.